# Handling Oracle Stored Procedure IN OUT Cursor using JDBC with JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, cursor, jboss5.x

I'm having a lot of issues trying to handle an IN OUT cursor for a stored procedure being called for an Oracle DB using JDBC.  You can see below how I've been calling/trying to call the stored procedure and handle the output.  This same code (with slight modifications in the commented out pieces) is used successfully to do effectively the same thing with an inline SQL select statement, but we'd like to obscure the structure and usage of the DB outside of the Java webservice, ideally.  Plus that method has performance issues.

I've found some very obscure forum posts about the web explaining that this either can't be done using JDBC with an IN OUT cursor or that there is some fundamental issue with the way JBoss ends up handling this DataSource connection (see my update below).

Depending on the various permutations in the way I'm casting the result of the callable statement, I'm seeing a nullPointerException or the following:

"Ref cursor is invalid"

The stored procedure parameters are defined as:

```
PROCEDURE "MYSTOREDPROC" (
cursor1 IN OUT MYPACKAGE.MYREFCURSOR,
parm1              IN VARCHAR2,
parm2              IN VARCHAR2) IS


public static final String CALL_TO_STORED_PROCEDURE = 
    "{ call MYSTOREDPROC(?, ?, ?) }";

conn = getConnection();

stmt = conn.prepareCall(CALL_TO_STORED_PROCEDURE );         
// Register the Out Parameter Type (Oracle Cursor)
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

// Set the Input Parameters
stmt.setString(2, p1);
stmt.setString(3, p2);

//result = stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.execute();
result = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);

while (result.next()) { // dostuff }
```

I've tried other ways to prepare the call such as:

```
//stmt = conn.prepareCall(CALL_TO_STORED_PROCEDURE , ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
//stmt = conn.prepareCall(CALL_TO_STORED_PROCEDURE , ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

**UPDATE:**

Using the condition below, I am able to cast the connection as an oracle specific connection and prepare the stored procedure call from that connection handle, yet I am still receiving a **(java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01001: invalid cursor)** when trying to reference the result of executing the callable statement.

```
if(conn instanceof org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection) {
WrappedConnection wc = (WrappedConnection)conn;
oconn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)wc.getUnderlyingConnection();
```

I'm sort of swinging in the dark at this point.  Is this potentially entirely related to Jboss 5.1? I have to imagine there is some way I can get this to work, but I know little to nothing about PL/SQL and the concept of cursors to even know what could be going wrong here.

Comment: How are you getting the connection? Via a datasource specified in oracle-ds.xml?

Comment: Sumit, that is correct, I am using a DataSource specified in the JBoss server in the 'deploy' directory.  I can't give out the details of this file for security reasons, but the driver specified is: <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>, and I know this file is properly working for prepared statements using inline SQL.

Comment: Do you know which version oracle jar is in the lib folder of jboss server(default\lib?production\lib)? also do you have an oracle jar in your war lib folder?